# Just setup ubuntu as webserver, what about my AMP setup on my other computer do I remove it?

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, lamp

My question is now that I have setup the Ubuntu web server do I have to remove the Apache Mysql and php from the laptop so it doesnt conflict with the server and/or can I migrate the working settings off my lappy to the ubuntu web server. 
P.s I have just setup up Ubuntu 14.4.1 server with LAMP for the purpose of web development server on a separate box on my network, before this I was working on my laptop (Mac powerbook) I have Apache2, Mysql and Php installed and running on the localhost from the laptop (everything from the lappy).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more clear what problem you want to solve? (And be more to the point)

Comment: You don't *have to* remove the MySQL server and the PHP software. Just make sure the programs on the server use the local ones, not the stuff remaining on your laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relax.

There is in general **no notion of "conflict"** between distinct web (and SQL) servers running on different machines - given, of course, that they aren't configured to share the same IP address, which would be a problem *in general*.

All you have to do is, of course, to make sure you use the *correct IP address or hostname for the machine* you want to "talk to", e.g. in the address bar.

The closest thing to "migrating" the settings I can think of would be copying `/etc/httpd.conf` (the Apache configuration file) from your laptop to the web server and editing it accordingly, but if you are not familiar with the `httpd.conf` syntax and semantics things could get ugly.

I suggest you simply configure your web server by hand, using the original configuration file as reference - for a development machine I can guess it can't be enormous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tobia will do that, its clearer now. I think whats happening is a tug of war between the apps, now only because its still configured to my laptop settings on the conf files. will go through it all. Cheers